# Problem with SELECT querys syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I can not figure out what is wrong with this syntax:

```
$categorynameresult='SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM categories WHERE company = '$companyName' AND cid IN(\''.$categoryids.'\')';
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ...

I know that $companyName and $categoryids have the values that I need, but there seems to be something wrong with the syntax Could sombody please help me? Thanks

Comment: The syntax highlighting in this post should give you a hint...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing the string prematurely with the single quotes around `'$companyName'`, which is why PHP is giving you a parse error.

You could fix this by escaping those quotes (like you're doing with `$companyids`), but variables aren't interpolated in single quoted strings anyways. Rather than simply escaping the single quotes, you need to use double quotes around the whole string:

```
$categorynameresult="SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM categories WHERE company = '$companyName' AND cid IN($categoryids)";
```

This assumes that `$categoryids` is a comma-separated list of numeric IDs.

Comment: @Henkka Remove the quotes and backslashes around `$categoryids` as per my query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$categorynameresult="SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM categories WHERE company = '$companyName' AND cid IN('$categoryids')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes around company name causes syntax error, try this:

```
$categorynameresult='SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM categories WHERE company = \''.$companyName.'\' AND cid IN(\''.$categoryids.'\')';
```

Comment: This is wrong. The $companyName would not be evaluated in this statement because it is enclosed in a single quoted string

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the concatenate operator:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM categories WHERE company = \'' . $companyName . '\' AND cid IN(\'' . $categoryids . '\')';
```

Comment: you definitely need single quotes around company name in sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is enclosed in `''`, while these also occur in the query - or, at least, try to do so.

Besides, you forgot to call `mysql_real_escape()` to escape your strings to be put into the query..